# Resolve levels in pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Assume, I have following pivoted DataFrame:

```
|   ID |   0 |   1 |   2 |
|    0                   |
|-----:|----:|----:|----:|
| 1115 | nan | "YE"| nan |
| 1590 | nan | "He"| "NO"|
```

How can I remove this `0` column, so that I get this representation:

```
|   ID |   0 |   1 |   2 |
|-----:|----:|----:|----:|
| 1115 | nan | "YE"| nan |
| 1590 | nan | "He"| "NO"|
```

Note: It is not a row.

EDIT:

Index:

```
df.index
Int64Index([   0,  2],
           dtype='int64', name=0, length=3)
```

Columns:

```
df.columns
Int64Index([   0,   1,   2],
           dtype='int64', name='ID', length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
del df.index.name
```

You just need to get rid of `index` `name` parameter.

Comment: ```TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable``` Int64Index([  0,1,2],
           dtype='int64', name='ID', length=3)

Comment: Can you share ```print(df.columns)``` and ```print(df.index)```

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Thanks, please check my answer now - this should do the trick

Comment: unfortunately, it says: ```AttributeError: can't delete attribute```

Comment: Hm, maybe you need to upgrade your ```pandas``` and/or python. Try instead: ```df.index.name=''``` (assign empty string to it)